# How to simplify the following expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to be able to simplify the following expression, if it is at all possible.

$$-\left(\frac{A}{3a} + \frac{B}{3b} + \frac{C}{3c}\right) \pm \frac{\sqrt{A^{2}(b^{2}c^{2}) + B^{2}(a^{2}c^{2}) + C^{2}(a^{2}b^{2}) - AB(abc^{2}) - AC(ab^{2}c) - BC(a^{2}bc)}}{3abc},$$

Thank you.

**Edit**

I believe that I can simplify it to the following, but I am not sure if this is the furthest that one can go to simplify the expression.

$$-\frac{1}{3}\left(\left(\frac{A}{a} + \frac{B}{b} + \frac{C}{c}\right) \mp \sqrt{\left(\frac{A^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{B^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{C^{2}}{c^{2}} - \frac{AB}{ab} - \frac{AC}{ac} - \frac{BC}{bc}\right)}\right),$$

Comment: That's probably as nice as it will get. You can simplify the denominator in the 6 terms in the root, maybe that will look nicer.

Comment: @Jeb How do I do that? Would you be able to write an answer to show me?

Comment: Use reduced variables $\alpha=A/a\cdots$:

$$\frac13\left(-\left({\alpha} + {\beta} + {\gamma}\right) \pm\sqrt{\alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2} + \alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \beta\gamma}\right)$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah, I see what you mean. Thank you very much! That is a great idea!

Comment: I will edit my now-deleted answer and then restore it.  Stand by.....

Comment: . . . It now appears that a correct version of what I had in mind goes like this: $2x^2y^2 + 2x^2z^2 + 2y^2z^2 - x^4 - y^4 - z^4$ $=(x+y+z)(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)\vphantom{\dfrac11}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Is this what would be inside of the square root?

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah, thank you!

Comment: @Michel Hardy:  I thought in Heron's formula for the area of a triangle (which is essentially what you suggest) but I could not see how this can help a simplification. I would see if indeed possible. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:You can go to the form $3X= -(\alpha +  \beta+\gamma) \pm\sqrt{(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^2 – (\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \beta\gamma)}$ and this is actually six times the roots of

$X^2 +(\alpha +  \beta+\gamma) X + \frac{(\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \beta\gamma)}{4}=0$.

I fear you could not simplify without additional conditions on your letters $A,B,C,a,b,c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I am afraid I do not understand how you have managed to convert the expression to a quadratic.

Comment: Try (with the formula you well know) to solve the quadratic equation  I gave you and see at the transformation gave by Yves Daoust which is more or less the same that mine